# How do I turn a storage pool back into a normal harddrive?

Tags: windows, windows-10

A while age I converted my Toshiba Harddrive into a storage pool so I could fit more storage onto my Windows 10 laptop. I no longer need it to be a storage pool anymore and want to convert it back to its original state so it can work like a normal harddrive again.

I tried doing this myself by going into the disk management place and deleting the volume on it, but then it disappeared and there was no option to convert it back to a basic disk which I thought would be the last step. It completely disappeared and I don't know how to access my drive anymore as I cannot find it anywhere in my computer.

All the help would be appreciated as this harddrive cost me an arm and a leg and I really want it to go back to normal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### I no longer need it to be a storage pool anymore

**Warning**:

When you delete a storage space, all files stored on it will be deleted permanently.

> **To delete a Storage space from a Storage pool in Windows 10**
>
> - [Open the Settings app](https://winaero.com/blog/all-ways-to-open-settings-app-in-windows-10/).
>
>   [image]
> - Go to System -> Storage.
> - On the right, click on the link Manage Storage Spaces.
>
>   [image]
> - In the next dialog, click on the button Change settings and confirm the UAC prompt.
>
>   [image]
> - Now, click on the link Delete on right side of the Storage space you want to delete under the appropriate Storage pool.
>
>   [image]
> - On the next page, click on the button Delete storage space to permanently delete the store space and all its data.
>
>   [image]
>
> Alternatively, you can use PowerShell to delete a Storage Space.
>
> **Delete a Storage Space from a Storage Pool with PowerShell**
>
> - [Open PowerShell as Administrator](http://winaero.com/blog/all-ways-to-open-powershell-in-windows-10/#elevated). Tip: [You can add "Open PowerShell As Administrator" context menu](http://winaero.com/blog/powershell-administrator-context-menu-windows-10/).
> - Type or copy-paste the following command: `Get-VirtualDisk`.
>
>   [image]Windows 10 List Storage Spaces
>     PowerShell
> - Note the `FriendlyName` value for the Storage Space you want to remove.
> - To remove the Storage space, run the command: `Remove-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName "The FriendlyName value"`. Use the actual name of a Storage Space you want to remove.
>
>   [image]
> - Enter "Y" to confirm the removal (see the screenshot above).

Source [Delete Storage Space from Storage Pool in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/delete-storage-space-storage-pool-windows-10/)